# CSS grid is not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have been working for many hours but still can't see what is wrong. The home page of the website https://www.deanstreetpress.co.uk/ has a top section with a slider, and a section below that with 4 columns. I am using CSS grid to set this up and it works perfectly on my local site using WAMP. the CSS code looks like this:

```
#home .cards-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 5fr 2fr 3fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
  height: 370px;
}
```

I set up a test section above it using blank divs with a red bg and, as you can see, that behaves as expected. However the actual section only displays 2 columns with the 3rd and 4th lining up below the 2nd column. I've tried eliminating the content from the divs, replacing them with blank divs etc but I still get the same result.

Can anyone suggest what is happening here? I emphasize that it works perfectly on my local WAMP site.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at it, seems the problem is an extra `<em>` [emphasis tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em) wapping the last 3 columns and therefore breaking the layout. Not sure if using this tag there makes sense.

See [Inspector Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qPhi.png) for reference

What are you trying to emphasize?

Comment: The <em> tags are not added by me - they are not in the base code and are unwanted but I can't see how to get rid of them. I thought they were maybe added by the browser

Comment: There is no doubt that the <em> tags you identified are the cause of the problem - I used 'edit as HTML' in Devtools, removed the <em> tags and all temporarily returned to normal - but where could they be coming from? They are not in my code and if the site has been hacked, it's a pretty odd sort of hack!

Comment: Without knowing your development/deployment setup is really hard to say how this is happening. Hope you figure it out tho. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The home page has a truncated version of the site blog. The truncation cut off a closing  tag and that was enough to break the layout. I have now applied a function to restore any missing closing tag and the layout has returned to expected.

Thanks to all who responded and I hope this may help others with a similar issue.